# Fast way to turn matrix columns into unit vectors

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, optimization, normalize

I have a matrix:

```
S = [  -1.0400    4.9100    4.1000   -3.5450   -0.6600   -0.9300    4.3950   -1.0650    2.9850   -4.9800    0.2100;
   -0.5200   -4.3150   -3.0950    0.5700    4.4700    1.1500    3.1350    0.6450    0.3750   -4.9150   -2.1150; 
    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000    5.0000 ];
```

I want to convert the columns to unit vectors, so I use a `for` loop

```
for i=1:size(S,2)
    S(:,i) = S(:,i) / norm( S(:,i) );
end
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently in MATLAB?

Comment: Please include the earliest relevant MATLAB version in your question, since some functions useful to your problem had only been introduced in recent releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR**

If you have MATLAB 2016b or newer, and no compatibility concerns, I would use

```
S = S ./ sqrt(sum(S.^2,1));
```

Edit: See benchmark at the bottom for performance benchmark of alternatives.

---

**Context**

We can just manually calculate the norm and divide column-wise.

By definition, `norm(x) = sqrt( sum( x(:).^2 ) )`. I've used `(:)` here to show that `norm` is calculated over the whole matrix. What's useful for us is that `sum` works column-wise by default, so the column-wise norm is defined like so:

```
nrm = sqrt( sum( x.^2 ) );
```

Note that if there's a possibility of your matrix `S` only having 1 row, you should ecplicitly enforce column-wise summation using `nrm = sqrt(sum(x.^2,1))`.

Now we have several options for division:

- Implicit expansion (MATLAB R2016b or newer)

  ```
  S = S ./ nrm;
  ```
- Implicit expansion using `bsxfun` (all MATLAB versions)

  ```
  S = bsxfun( @mrdivide, S, nrm );
  ```
- Manual expansion using `repmat` (all MATLAB versions)

  ```
  S = S ./ repmat(nrm, size(S,1), 1);
  ```

---

If you have MATLAB R2017b or newer, and again no compatability concerns, you can use `vecnorm`, which can be used in place of the manual norm calculation

```
S = S ./ vecnorm(S, 2, 1);
```

---

**Benchmark:**

Since you asked for performance, here is a simple benchmark for testing the speed of these different methods. Specifically the original loop in your question versus implicit expansion with either `vecnorm` or the manual calculation.

- Results (run using R2017b)

  ```
           size(S):  1e3*1e2  1e5*1e3  1e3*1e6    
           Looping:  0.0005   1.0186   12.7788
   Implicit manual:  0.0001   1.1236   10.4031
  Implicit vecnorm:  0.0002   0.5774    6.8058
  ```
- Conclusions

  - For relatively small arrays, all of the methods are very fast and I would opt for code clarity over performance.
  - If you only want to use MATLAB versions which support it, `vecnorm` is approximately twice as quick as other methods for large matrices.
  - For matrices of the order `1e5*1e3`, looping is comparable to implicit expansion.
- Code

  ```
  function benchie()
      S = rand( 1e3, 1e2 )*5;

      f1 = @() loopingNorm(S);
      f2 = @() implicitManual(S);
      f3 = @() implicitVecnorm(S);

      fprintf( 'Looping: %.4f\nImplicit manual: %.4f\nImplicit vecnorm: %.4f\n', ...
               timeit(f1), timeit(f2), timeit(f3) );
  end
  function S = loopingNorm(S)
      for ii = 1:size(S,2)
          S(:,ii) = S(:,ii) / norm( S(:,ii) );
      end
  end
  function S = implicitManual(S)
      S = S ./ sqrt(sum(S.^2,1));
  end
  function S = implicitVecnorm(S)
      S = S ./ vecnorm( S, 2, 1 );
  end
  ```

Comment: In 2018a and later, there is also a `normalize` function which (with the 'norm' method selected) looks like it does the entire job. But that's even less backwards compatible...

Comment: @etmuse It's August 2018, everyone should have paid to upgrade their licenses by now, *right*?? Thanks for the info, looks like the syntax would be `S = normalize(S, 1, 'norm')`, although I can't validate.

Comment: @etmuse one thing to note though, is that `normalize` uses `vecnorm` under the hood (it's open-source). Also, it automatically treats NaNs as zeros - which might be an unwanted side-effect in some cases. Judging by the amount of logic in that function, I wouldn't say it's the most efficient alternative out there... A valid suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning which MATLAB version was used for the benchmark, seeing how `for`-loop and other optimizations were introduced in various versions (in other words, results depends somewhat on the local MATLAB version).

Comment: @Dev-iL Fair point, I always normally include version in benchie results, forgot but added now :)